# Conflicts between dns name to real machine host-name and impact about ssh connections

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, resolution, resolv.conf

I want to share the picture about our cluster with machines rhel 7.5 . DNS server include the following names (example)

We can see that "`S`" is capital letter:

```
BD_Server1
BD_Server2
BD_Server3
BD_Server4
```

But the Linux machines `/etc/hostname` are the following hosts.

We can see that "`s`" is small letter:

```
BD_server1
BD_server2
BD_server3
BD_server4
```

Is this a problem that can cause `SSH` issues, when we set capital character on the DNS server, when Linux machine name is with small latter?

For now we have good tests as

```
host BD_server4
host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ping localhost
```

and `resolve.conf` is set correctly.

Comment: Case does not matter. Try e.g. `ping LOCALhost`.

Comment: we have ping to local host and also te resolving is ok , i mean we have resolving to hostname and ip's

Comment: ssh can't know about server name (e.g. return from `hostname`), ssh only know about names and IP, you might have 2 lines in know_hosts for BD_Server and BD_server, but that's about all.

Comment: Have you tried to configure different address in `/etc/hosts`, and tested what it resolves to? I mean, the question is easy to answer by just trying it out ...

Comment: I am not using hosts file - because I am using the DNS server for resolving